# Firebase spamming purchase report logs

Tags: swift, firebase, in-app-purchase, firebase-analytics

At app launch the console is spammed with logs of form :

> 4.8.1 - [Firebase/Analytics][***********] Purchase is a duplicate and will not be reported. Product ID: ...

I am working with auto-renewable subscriptions and am getting aprox 35 of these at launch.
Version of Xcode : 9.2 , Version of Firebase : 3.17.4

How can this be fixed ?

Comment: I got same error. Do you find any solution?

Comment: Perhaps try a different sandbox account? That seems to have fixed it for me =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the release note (https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios), the new In-App Purchase report was released on 4.0.7 and it improved the report. The reason you see the log is that there have been duplicate transactions and Analytics will not report those duplicate transactions to avoid inflating the life-time value. 
Since you are in sandbox, auto-renewable subscriptions are more frequent than in released app (and it could be annoying if you turn on debug mode) but it is necessary if something happens with your report like missing IAP events and you report the problem to Firebase support.

Comment: But my purchase was expired (I have cancelled the subscription from settings). But didupdatetransaction delegate method called with purchased status. Any solution?

Answer (score 6):

You can set the logger level to minimum with the following code:

```
FirebaseConfiguration.shared().setLoggerLevel(.min)
FirebaseApp.configure()
```

Comment: well that is handy but I rather was wondering about why I got those as if a purchase was made ?